# haskell IO() whats wrong here?

Tags: haskell, input, io

hey i have been doing haskell and with one of my sheets i was asked to do a buildList

i got

```
buildList :: [String] -> IO ()
buildList thelist = do
putStr "Enter a line: "
str <- getLine
if str == ""
  then return ()
  else do let list = str:thelist
          print list
          buildList list
```

I also had to add a listBuilder :: IO () as well which when ever i try to run I get a weird error

```
ERROR file:.\week8.hs:92 - Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')
```

it came to the conclusion that there is something wrong with the buildList, even though it works, as I cant put any new function underneath it, even ones that dont need to use the buildList function

if anyone knows how to fix this, it would be much appreciated. thanks

~tom

Comment: Your conclusion is probably wrong. `buildList` works fine, please show us `listBuilder` instead.

Comment: i know it works but when ever i put a new function underneath it, whether it will be using buildList or not, It doesnt work, so its buildList not anything else.

Comment: Which line is line 92 (the line where the error is reported)?

Answer (score 2):

Indent the body of the function so the parser knows where it ends.